# $\cos \alpha$/$\cos \beta$=a, $\sin \alpha$/$\sin \beta$=b then $\sin^2\beta$ is

Tags: trigonometry

Trigonometry help:
$\cos \alpha$/$\cos \beta$=a,
$\sin \alpha$/$\sin \beta$=b then $\sin^2\beta$ is.

Note:
$\sin \beta$
=b/$\sin \alpha$

Comment: I've noticed that you have asked 10 questions recently during your first four days on the site. I wanted to make sure that you are aware of the quotas 50 questions/30 days and 6 questions/24 hours, so that you can plan posting your questions accordingly. (If you try to post more questions, StackExchange software will not allow you to do so.) For more details see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4770/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\cos\alpha=a\cos\beta$ and $\sin\alpha=b\sin\beta$. Square both sides of both equations and add. We get
$$1=a^2\cos^2\beta+b^2\sin^2\beta.\tag{1}$$
Now use the fact that $\cos^2\beta=1-\sin^2\beta$. Substitute in Equation (1), and $\sin^2\beta$ is a small step away.

Comment: 1=$a^2$-$(a^2-b^2)sin ^2 \beta$.@Andre'Nicolas.is it right?

Comment: You are asked for $\sin^2\beta$, so you want to solve, getting $\sin^2\beta=\frac{1-a^2}{b^2-a^2}$ or if you prefer $\frac{a^2-1}{a^2-b^2}$.

Comment: yes how sin^2β =1/a^2-(a^2−^b2).yes you are correct but this is the answer from i got from the above equation.@Andre'Nicolas

Comment: To get $\sin^2\beta$ start from your expression in your first comment. I prefer to write it as $1=a^2+(b^2-a^2)\sin^2\beta$. Bring the $a^2$ to the other side. We get $1-a^2=(b^2-a^2)\sin^2\beta$. Now divide both sides by $b^2-a^2$, and we get $\sin^2\beta$.